# Rewriting C macro code with VIM search & replace

Tags: regex, vim, replace

I've got a file that uses an outdated macro to read 32 bit integers,

```
READ32(dest, src)
```

I need to replace all calls with

```
dest = readUint32(&src);
```

I'm trying to write a SED style Vim search & replace command, but not having luck.

I can match the 1st part using `READ32([a-z]\+, cmd)` using the `/` search prompt, but it does not seem to match in the `:s` syntax.

Comment: Can you paste in the `:s` command you have tried?

Answer (score 1):

Here's what I finally figured out to work:

`:%s/READ32(\(\a\+\),\(\a\+\)/\1 = readUint32(\&\2);`

The trick is wrapping the values you want to store in `\1` & `\2` in `\(` and `\)`  The other trick was you have to escape the `&` operator as & in vim replacement is "the whole match".

EDIT: improved further as I refined it:
`:%s/READ32(\(\w\+\),\s*\(\w\+\)/\1 = readUint32(\&\2);`

Changed `\a` to `\w` as I had variables with _ in them.
Added \s* to take care of white space issues between the , and second variable.
Now just trying to deal with c++ style variables of style class.variable.subvariable

EDIT 2: 
replaced `\w` with `[a-zA-Z0-9_.]` to catch all of the ways my variables were named.

Answer (score 0):

This should do what you want or at least get you started:

```
%s-READ32(\s*\(\i\+\)\s*,\s*\(\i\+\)\s*)-\1 = readUint32(\&\2);-g
```

Answer (score 0):

I'd do the macro style again: hit <kbd>*</kbd> to 'highlight' search for `READ32`.

Now, we are going to record a macro (<kbd>q</kbd>..<kbd>q</kbd><kbd>q</kbd>):

- <kbd>n</kbd> 
               (*move to next match*)
- <kbd>c</kbd><kbd>w</kbd>`readUint32`<kbd>Esc</kbd> 
               (*change the function name*)
- <kbd>w</kbd><kbd>w</kbd><kbd>dt,</kbd> 
               (*delete the first argument*)
- <kbd>"_dw</kbd> 
               (*remove the redundant `,`*)
- <kbd>b</kbd><kbd>b</kbd><kbd>P</kbd><kbd>a</kbd>`=`<kbd>Esc</kbd> 
               (*insert the result variable appending `=` before `readUint32`*)
- <kbd>A</kbd><kbd>;</kbd>
               (*append `;` to the end of the line*)

Now you can just repeat the macro (`1000@q`).